# Increase performance on Varchar index on a Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, indexing

we had to change the key in our database from bigint to varchar because our customer wishes so.

Before the change the key had three columns:

```
cust_id bigint, schema TEXT produkt_name TEXT
```

Now:

```
cust_id VARCHAR(50) schema TEXT produkt_name TEXT
```

after the change everything is incredible slow.

I thought I could may create a hashed Index von cust_id but is that even possible because its part of the primary key?
Or is there any effect of this?

May there are other ways to optimze.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please also read: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: By default, `VARCHAR` columns use Unicode collation, which makes index lookups significantly slower. Try declaring your column as `cust_id VARCHAR(50) COLLATE "C"`.

Comment: Let's see the table schema.